# Smarty reading last x numbers of rows of an array

Tags: php, smarty

I need to read for example last 3 items of an array in smarty.
Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this

```
 {assign var=lastRows value=$array|array_slice:-3}
```

And after this you may use `$lastRows` in any way you want.
You should also take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: Worked for me when I added "@" in front of "array_slice":
`{assign var=lastRows value=$array|@array_slice:-3}`

Comment: @Janis: '@' was required for arrays in Smarty 2.x. Its not required anymore in 3.x (but its still supported).

Answer (score 0):

```
{foreach from=$array item=row name=foo}
{if $smarty.foreach.foo.index >= $smarty.foreach.foo.total - 3}
    {$row}
{/if}
{/foreach}
```